# How to deploy Java Webapp on Netbeans to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am developing a Java web application in `Netbeans IDE 7.1.1`. The IDE comes with pre-installed `Apache Tomcat 7.0`.

The folder structure in Netbeans looks like this

[image]

All the servlet are in `Source Packages` and have added two in `Libraries` - MySQL JDBC Driver and Apache Commons Collection in `Libraries` folder.

Now I want to deploy this on `Amazon Web Services - Elastic Beanstalk'. The documentation of AWS Elastic Beanstalk (beta) says`
Package your deployable code into a standard Java Web Application Archive (WAR file) and Upload your WAR file to Elastic Beanstalk using the AWS Management Console`

**My Question**

How to package my deployable code into `WAR file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already running your app, then `WAR` should be in `Files/dist` folder in the root of your project. Otherwise deploying your app should create this folder with the war file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the image of folder structure because could not find the `/dist` folder anywhere.

Comment: Locate it in the folder of your project in the filesystem, not in NetBeans. Or look to the Files tab, you can explore your project folders there (dist folder included)

Comment: Ok, it is in `Files` tab. How I could not see it? Thanks so much. Can  you edit you answer to include this comment, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**With NetBeans 7.2, you can use the new cloud feature:**

http://wiki.netbeans.org/AmazonBeanstalkSupport :-)

Answer (score -1):

is the http://wiki.netbeans.org/AmazonBeanstalkSupport support gone in Netbeans 8? as I can't find it and also when search online it indicates that option only in NetBeans 7.2.